# regular expression replace reserve part of the original string

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I want to replace the text

```
Tag="...",
```

with

```
<Header="...", Style=Something>
```

while reserving the `...` part. Can I do it with regular expression or some features of Sublime Text? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you prefer. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*..

```
Find What: Tag="([^"]+)",
Replace With: <Header="\1", Style=Something>
```

Answer (score 1):

For content like this:

```
Tag="this is a \"simple\" test",
```

pattern: `Tag="((?>\\.|[^"])*)",`

Replace: `<Header="\1", Style=Something>`